# ffprobe - How to limit stream info in the output to just the video bitrate?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffprobe

If I run *FFprobe* on an .MKV file, with the simplest syntax of `FFprobe "TheMovie.mkv"`, there is a lot of output I don't need to see.
How do I limit the output of *FFprobe* to just the *bitrate* of the video stream?

I've researched the resources http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe-all.html#Synopsis and https://hintsandmemories.wordpress.com/2014/04/16/ffprobe-help-output/
but these are bit steep for a simple history teacher, so I ask forgiveness for not being able to figure that out. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1 "input.mp4"
```

Comment: Did you try this with MKV input? OP is asking about MKV, but your command will likely output `bit_rate=N/A`.

Comment: Thanks for reacting, but the result is **bitrate = N/A**  while ffprobe "input.mkv" results in a **bitrate 932Kb/s** Please see my screenshot 

https://pasteboard.co/K3pukzl.jpg

Comment: @llogan You're correct. Every MKV file with videocodec **V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC**, (according to MediaInfo) gets the output **bit_rate=N/A** .  Files with video codec **avc1** do get a resulting bitrate.  Do you know any way to improve upon this??
When I use merely ffprobe, there's always an output where the bit rate is displayed in a very readable manner, *1 400 kb/s*

Comment: Sorry, didn't test it with mkv but thought that the result would be the same, I also get bit_rate=N/A with mkv file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using the  **-hide_banner** switch is doing the trick.

So, the command is gonna be:

```
ffprobe -i "input.mkv" -hide_banner
```

It's not a perfect solution, because then the output would JUST be the line with the bitrate in kb/s, but this will do. Any answers which do that, I will give them  my blessing. This works on files with videocodec **V_MPEG4/ISO/AVC**, and video codec **avc1**. No "**bit_rate=N/A**" output-duds whatsoever.

Remarks:

- This also works with **ffmpeg**, but it then starts to complain via error massage about output files.
- Combined with a registry hack plus a batch file, it's possible to add this to the context menu. Which I have done.
- Perhaps a modification could be made so it works on other formats like mp4 and avi, tóó, but that is for another time.